# Text getting cropped from bottom in select tag telugu language

Tags: html, text

Text is getting cropped from bottom

```html
<select placeholder="అడ్రెస్ ప్రూఫ్">
  <option value="AADHAAR">ఆధార్ కార్డు</option>
  <option value="VOTER_ID">ఓటర్ ఐడి</option>
  <option value="PASSPORT">పాస్పోర్ట్</option>
</select>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/garvitrajput/pen/ExZbjPm

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what is being cut off are the [descenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender) of the characters. I don't really think you can prevent this - i would recommend setting the height of the select tag in CSS.

For example:

```
select {
    font-size: 1em;
    height: 1.7em;
}
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: And what browser do you use?